# How to unpack nested DBRef in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, pymongo, dbref

How do you unpack nested DBRefs?

I have checked the mongodb [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) but I still do not quite understand how to unpack the alphanumeric value within the brackets.

```
d = { 
    "oId" : 567, 
    "notice" : [
        DBRef("noticeId", ObjectId("5f45177b93d7b757bcbd2d55"))
    ]
}
```

Expected Output:

```
oId                   notice
567 5f45177b93d7b757bcbd2d55
```

Comment: You can use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) to find out what attributes an object has! `DBRef` likely has some id attributes you can get at (and it may may in turn be there's a convenience on calling `str()` on `ObjectId`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `id` attribute of the `DBRef` object. [Documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/dbref.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from bson.json_util import DBRef, ObjectId

d = {
    "oId": 567,
    "notice": [
        DBRef("noticeId", ObjectId("5f45177b93d7b757bcbd2d55"))
    ]
}

data = {'oId': [d.get('oId')], 'notice': [str(d.get('notice')[0].id)]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

gives:

```
   oId                    notice
0  567  5f45177b93d7b757bcbd2d55
```

Comment: is there a way to actually convert it into a dataframe instead of just retrieving the values?